# Shift the value of the elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

goodmornig, I have a list of numbers like this:

```
data= {{0.00164, 60.36666}, {0.00328, 61.63334}, {0.00492, 
53.93333}, {0.00656, 42.56667}, {0.0082, 38.7}, {0.00984, 
34.43333}, {0.01148, 50.43333}, {0.01312, 
37.13334}, {0.01476, 32.96667}, {0.0164, 47.3}, {0.01804, 
42.16667}, {0.01968, 30.26667}, {0.02132, 
48.23333}, {0.02296, 40.76667}, {0.0246, 35.26667}, {0.02624,
 40.33333}, {0.02788, 41.3}, {0.02952, 34.73333}, {0.03116, 
39.56667}, {0.0328, 35.7}, {0.03444, 36.5}, {0.03608, 
34.7}, {0.03772, 36.76667}, {0.03936, 33.6}, {0.041, 
39.16667}, {0.04264, 33.43333}, {0.04428, 
34.66667}, {0.04592, 34.6}, {0.04756, 35.83333}, {0.0492, 
31.9}, {0.05084, 36.2}, {0.05248, 31.2}, {0.05412, 
32.46667}, {0.05576, 31.56667}, {0.0574, 33.53333}, {0.05904,
 28.83333}, {0.06068, 32.46667}, {0.06232, 28.}, {0.06396, 
30.4}, {0.0656, 28.66667}, {0.06724, 31.46667}, {0.06888, 
28.8}, {0.07052, 31.83333}, {0.07216, 27.43333}, {0.0738, 
29.1}, {0.07544, 28.73333}, {0.07708, 29.83333}, {0.07872, 
26.13333}, {0.08036, 28.66667}, {0.082, 25.46667}, {0.08364, 
27.03333}, {0.08528, 25.16667}, {0.08692, 
25.96667}, {0.08856, 22.8}, {0.0902, 26.03333}, {0.09184, 
23.6}, {0.09348, 25.}, {0.09512, 23.2}, {0.09676, 
24.1}, {0.0984, 21.26667}, {0.10004, 25.36667}, {0.10168, 
22.03333}, {0.10332, 24.2}, {0.10496, 20.86667}, {0.1066, 
23.96667}, {0.10824, 20.1}, {0.10988, 21.03333}, {0.11152, 
19.6}, {0.11316, 22.26667}, {0.1148, 20.}, {0.11644, 
22.4}, {0.11808, 19.66667}, {0.11972, 20.3}, {0.12136, 
15.53333}, {0.123, 19.83333}, {0.12464, 18.66667}, {0.12628, 
19.63333}, {0.12792, 18.1}, {0.12956, 21.06667}, {0.1312, 
17.9}, {0.13284, 18.03333}, {0.13448, 15.13333}, {0.13612, 
19.93333}, {0.13776, 15.36667}, {0.1394, 16.73333}, {0.14104,
 14.83333}, {0.14268, 17.33333}, {0.14432, 
15.43333}, {0.14596, 17.26667}, {0.1476, 14.36667}, {0.14924,
 18.16667}, {0.15088, 14.7}, {0.15252, 15.6}, {0.15416, 
13.23333}, {0.1558, 16.}, {0.15744, 13.23333}, {0.15908, 
16.3}, {0.16072, 13.46667}, {0.16236, 14.56667}, {0.164, 
12.26667}, {0.16564, 14.36667}, {0.16728, 
12.43333}, {0.16892, 13.96667}, {0.17056, 12.43333}, {0.1722,
 14.6}, {0.17384, 11.}, {0.17548, 14.26667}, {0.17712, 
11.73333}, {0.17876, 12.6}, {0.1804, 10.}, {0.18204, 
13.5}, {0.18368, 10.63333}, {0.18532, 12.13333}, {0.18696, 
10.43333}, {0.1886, 10.8}, {0.19024, 8.733334}, {0.19188, 
11.66667}, {0.19352, 10.53333}, {0.19516, 12.56667}, {0.1968,
 10.26667}, {0.19844, 10.8}, {0.20008, 7.8}, {0.20172, 
10.}, {0.20336, 9.533334}, {0.205, 8.233334}, {0.20664, 
7.}, {0.20828, 8.9}, {0.20992, 7.933333}, {0.21156, 
9.066667}, {0.2132, 6.4}, {0.21484, 8.266666}, {0.21648, 
6.466667}, {0.21812, 8.166667}, {0.21976, 6.}, {0.2214, 
9.566667}, {0.22304, 7.1}, {0.22468, 9.566667}, {0.22632, 
6.566667}, {0.22796, 8.833333}, {0.2296, 6.433333}, {0.23124,
 7.6}, {0.23288, 5.433333}, {0.23452, 9.5}, {0.23616, 
5.233333}, {0.2378, 6.866667}, {0.23944, 6.2}, {0.24108, 
8.9}, {0.24272, 6.266667}, {0.24436, 7.333333}, {0.246, 
4.6}, {0.24764, 6.833333}, {0.24928, 4.566667}, {0.25092, 
6.266667}, {0.25256, 3.5}, {0.2542, 5.966667}, {0.25584, 
4.9}, {0.25748, 4.866667}, {0.25912, 2.533333}, {0.26076, 
5.766667}, {0.2624, 5.333333}, {0.26404, 5.566667}, {0.26568,
 4.633333}, {0.26732, 6.1}, {0.26896, 1.6}, {0.2706, 
5.4}, {0.27224, 5.233333}, {0.27388, 7.533333}, {0.27552, 
4.666667}, {0.27716, 6.466667}, {0.2788, 4.166667}, {0.28044,
 6.766667}, {0.28208, 4.066667}, {0.28372, 5.7}, {0.28536, 
2.4}, {0.287, 4.4}, {0.28864, 2.533333}, {0.29028, 
2.566667}, {0.29192, 1.3}, {0.29356, 5.866667}, {0.2952, 
4.7}, {0.29684, 4.533333}, {0.29848, 1.933333}, {0.30012, 
5.333333}, {0.30176, 3.333333}, {0.3034, 5.366667}, {0.30504,
 2.233333}, {0.30668, 2.766667}, {0.30832, 
0.8666667}, {0.30996, 3.733333}, {0.3116, 
2.566667}, {0.31324, 5.033333}, {0.31488, 
1.966667}, {0.31652, 1.633333}, {0.31816, 
0.6333333}, {0.3198, 3.833333}, {0.32144, 
1.933333}, {0.32308, 
2.633333}, {0.32472, -0.2333333}, {0.32636, 
3.}, {0.328, -0.1}, {0.32964, 
2.966667}, {0.33128, -0.7}, {0.33292, 2.5}, {0.33456, 
0.7}, {0.3362, 2.5}, {0.33784, -0.6}, {0.33948, 
2.833333}, {0.34112, 1.366667}, {0.34276, 2.533333}, {0.3444,
 0.1666667}, {0.34604, 3.4}, {0.34768, 0.4}, {0.34932, 
3.166667}, {0.35096, 0.7666667}, {0.3526, 
1.933333}, {0.35424, -0.7333333}, {0.35588, 
2.266667}, {0.35752, -0.6}, {0.35916, 3.1}, {0.3608, 
0.5}, {0.36244, 
3.}, {0.36408, -1.233333}, {0.36572, -0.03333334}, {0.36736, \
-0.5}, {0.369, 2.666667}, {0.37064, -0.5333334}, {0.37228, 
2.366667}, {0.37392, 1.633333}, {0.37556, 2.7}, {0.3772, 
0.3333333}, {0.37884, 0.1}, {0.38048, -0.8333333}, {0.38212, 
0.7666667}, {0.38376, -0.1333333}, {0.3854, 
0.8}, {0.38704, -0.6}, {0.38868, 
1.766667}, {0.39032, -0.2333333}, {0.39196, 
2.1}, {0.3936, -0.5}, {0.39524, 
1.133333}, {0.39688, -1.6}, {0.39852, 0.9666666}, {0.40016, 
0.03333334}, {0.4018, 
0.03333334}, {0.40344, -0.3333333}, {0.40508, 
1.366667}, {0.40672, -1.4}, {0.40836, 
0.9}, {0.41, -0.1}, {0.41164, 
0.1333333}, {0.41328, -2.666667}, {0.41492, 
0.6}, {0.41656, -0.2}, {0.4182, 
0.6}, {0.41984, -3.233333}, {0.42148, -1.566667}, {0.42312, \
-0.5666667}, {0.42476, 
1.533333}, {0.4264, -1.833333}, {0.42804, -0.3333333}, \
{0.42968, -1.333333}, {0.43132, 
0.6666667}, {0.43296, -1.533333}, {0.4346, -0.3}, {0.43624, \
-1.833333}, {0.43788, 
0.1666667}, {0.43952, -0.4666667}, {0.44116, 
0.9333333}, {0.4428, -0.9333333}, {0.44444, -0.5666667}, \
{0.44608, -3.}, {0.44772, 
0.5666667}, {0.44936, -0.8333333}, {0.451, 
1.966667}, {0.45264, 0.4}, {0.45428, 
1.766667}, {0.45592, -0.2333333}, {0.45756, 
1.}, {0.4592, -0.5666667}, {0.46084, 
1.233333}, {0.46248, -2.033333}, {0.46412, -2.833333}, \
{0.46576, -3.233333}, {0.4674, -0.2333333}, {0.46904, \
-2.533333}, {0.47068, -1.066667}, {0.47232, -1.333333}, \
{0.47396, 
0.4666667}, {0.4756, -2.466667}, {0.47724, -0.3666667}, \
{0.47888, -1.1}, {0.48052, 
1.366667}, {0.48216, -1.466667}, {0.4838, -2.033333}, \
{0.48544, -2.233333}, {0.48708, -0.3666667}, {0.48872, \
-1.433333}, {0.49036, 1.1}, {0.492, -0.5333334}, {0.49364, 
0.2333333}, {0.49528, -2.233333}, {0.49692, -1.033333}, \
{0.49856, -0.8666667}, {0.5002, 
0.9666666}, {0.50184, -2.333333}, {0.50348, 
0.4333333}, {0.50512, -1.433333}, {0.50676, -3.066667}, \
{0.5084, -3.333333}, {0.51004, 
0.06666667}, {0.51168, -0.3666667}, {0.51332, 
1.166667}, {0.51496, -0.8}, {0.5166, 
0.8666667}, {0.51824, -2.2}, {0.51988, -1.766667}, {0.52152, \
-3.666667}, {0.52316, 0.2}, {0.5248, -0.06666667}, {0.52644, 
0.}, {0.52808, -1.3}, {0.52972, -0.5333334}, {0.53136, \
-1.4}, {0.533, -0.2}, {0.53464, -2.4}, {0.53628, -1.133333}, \
{0.53792, -2.8}, {0.53956, -1.4}, {0.5412, -2.033333}, \
{0.54284, -1.166667}, {0.54448, -2.166667}, {0.54612, -1.}, \
{0.54776, -2.466667}, {0.5494, -0.9666666}, {0.55104, -1.6}, \
{0.55268, -1.5}, {0.55432, -2.5}, {0.55596, -1.4}, {0.5576, \
-1.366667}, {0.55924, -0.1333333}, {0.56088, -2.633333}, \
{0.56252, -0.2666667}, {0.56416, -0.7666667}, {0.5658, \
-1.033333}, {0.56744, -3.366667}, {0.56908, -1.366667}, \
{0.57072, -2.5}, {0.57236, -0.2333333}, {0.574, -3.033333}, \
{0.57564, -1.466667}, {0.57728, -1.566667}, {0.57892, -0.1}, \
{0.58056, -2.033333}, {0.5822, -0.8}, {0.58384, -1.833333}, \
{0.58548, -0.9666666}, {0.58712, -2.9}, {0.58876, -0.9333333}, \
{0.5904, -1.766667}, {0.59204, -0.9333333}, {0.59368, \
-1.666667}, {0.59532, -0.2666667}, {0.59696, -2.4}, {0.5986, \
-2.6}, {0.60024, -2.466667}, {0.60188, 
0.06666667}, {0.60352, -1.966667}, {0.60516, 
0.1666667}, {0.6068, -2.5}, {0.60844, -1.466667}, {0.61008, \
-1.833333}, {0.61172, -0.8333333}, {0.61336, -2.1}, {0.615, \
-2.066667}, {0.61664, -2.266667}, {0.61828, -2.6}, {0.61992, \
-2.3}, {0.62156, -1.766667}, {0.6232, -3.233333}, {0.62484, \
-0.5}, {0.62648, -2.433333}, {0.62812, -2.433333}, {0.62976, \
-3.833333}, {0.6314, -1.033333}, {0.63304, -2.166667}, {0.63468,
 0.8333333}, {0.63632, -1.9}, {0.63796, 
0.2}, {0.6396, -1.9}, {0.64124, -1.5}, {0.64288, \
-2.733333}, {0.64452, -0.3333333}, {0.64616, -0.9333333}, \
{0.6478, -0.06666667}, {0.64944, -3.433333}, {0.65108, -2.7}, \
{0.65272, -2.166667}}
```

I want to find the min value of the second elements (in this case it seem to be -3.43333) and then shift all second elements by that value (in this case +3.433333) creating a new list. Can you help me?

Comment: Use indexing to grab all the elements of the second column : `Min[data[[All, 2]]]` (output: `-3.83333`) and use `MapAt` to shift every single element: `MapAt[# + 3.833333 &, data, {All, 2}]`

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to do this, here is one taking advantage of [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html)

```
SubsetMap[#-Min[#]&,data, {All,2}]
```

Or alternatively for speed (Using [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html), [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) and [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html))

```
Block[
 {
   x=data[[All, 1]],
   y=data[[All, 2]],
   min
 },
 min = Min[y];
 Transpose[{x,y-min}]
]
```

Or avoiding `Part`...

```
 Block[
   {x,y},
   {x,y}=Transpose@data;
   Transpose[{x,y-Min[y]}]
 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Comparing the timings

```
RepeatedTiming[data2 = SubsetMap[# - Min[#] &, data, {All, 2}];] (* rhermans *)

(* {0.00151529, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[min = Min[Transpose[data][[2]]]; 
 data3 = data /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y - min};] (* Alexei Boubitch *)

(* {0.000237703, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[
 data4 = (min = Min[data[[All, 2]]]; (# - {0, min}) & /@ data);]

(* {0.000131082, Null} *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
RepeatedTiming[
 data5 = Block[{x = data[[All, 1]], y = data[[All, 2]], min}, min = Min[y];
    Transpose[{x, y - min}]];] (* rhermans *)

(* {0.0000810067, Null} *)
```

Verifying equivalence of results,

```
data2 === data3 === data4 === data5

(* True *)
```

Comment: Any insights that may explain to some extent the time differences?

Comment: @rhermans - My assumptions: `SubsetMap` is designed to handle a broad range of inputs and carries more overhead to provide that flexibility. The other approaches are highly tailored to this specific problem. Rule-based replacements add pattern matching tests in addition to the basic operation being performed. However, if the problem is a one-time deal as opposed to being used repeatedly, the timing is of far less importance than the user's ease of programming, i.e., whatever readily comes to mind is best.

Comment: It seems that avoiding defining min using `With` or `Block` speeds things a bit too, see my edit.

Comment: data[[All,2]] -= Min[data[[All,2]]] is even faster, for small data sets such as the one above. For larger datasets (I did a RandomReal with 1 million pairs) it seems that rhermans method is winning by a bit. Nevertheless, if one wants to keep this kind of calculations fast, one should have an individual list for each column instead of combining them into a table.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following. The next statement yields the minimal second value:

```
min = Min[Transpose[data][[2]]]

(*  -3.83333  *)
```

and this makes the shift:

```
data2 = data /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y - min};
```

In the new data the minimum second value will be zero:

```
min2 = Min[Transpose[data2][[2]]]

(*  0.  *)
```

Let us plot them:

```
ListPlot[{data, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Why do you use transpose when you could simply do Min[data[[All,2]]] ?

Comment: @a20 Why not? These things are the same, are they not?

Comment: they produce the same result, but transposing the whole list first takes a lot longer time, about a factor of 4 difference on my computer. I do not know how they are implemented.

Comment: @a20 If you take `AbsoluteTiming` you will find that the former approach takes 0.00009 s and the latter 0.00006 s. This difference is not worth discussing. Of course, another story if the OP will start working on lists at least, 100 000 times greater than the one shown as `data`. However, it does not seem to be the case.  A nice thing about Mma is that in it almost every problem can be solved in several ways, and each of us chooses the way better corresponding to his personality: I choose this and you that.

Comment: for me it was 0.000057 s for the former approach and 0.000016 s for the latter. This is quite big and could certainly play a role if OP is working on larger datasets or needs to repeat the operation many times. Please do not misunderstand me, I was not looking to criticize you. I was just curious why you chose to transpose it first, if you had some special reason for it, when there is a more "straight forward" way.

Comment: @a20 I do not take it as a criticism (though I have nothing against criticism as well). It is a long-standing discussion. Indeed, people with a programmatic background tend to search for the fastest solution. Logically, however, if one needs a really fast solution he takes another soft, like C or Fortran or another fast compiler.  Typically, one uses Mma in the case when the timing is not the main problem. In many cases, the problems we try to solve with Mma are not that time-consuming. In this case, the bottleneck maybe the question "How fast it takes you to search for the solution?"

Comment: I think we are getting off track here. I was just wondering if there was a special reason for you to transpose it before using Part instead of just using Part. Even though problems can be solved in a plenitude of ways, producing the same end result, there can be subtle differences that might, objectively, make one method better than another. Doing a transpose first is a longer route, and that is why I thought you might be using it for a special reason. But I take it you are not?

Answer (score 2):

To get the minimum value `min` from the second column of `data`, here are a few variants:

```
MinimalBy[data, Last][[1, -1]]
RankedMin[data[[All, 2]], 1]
TakeSmallestBy[data, Last, 1][[1, -1]]
SortBy[data, Last][[1, -1]]

d3 = MapThread[{#1, #2 - min} &, Transpose@data];

ListPlot[{data, d3}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = 
 {{0.0016, 60.3}, {0.0032, 61.6}, {0.0049, 53.9}, 
  {0.0065, 42.5}, {0.0082, 38.7}, {0.0098, 34.4}};
```

Using `ArrayReduce` (new in 12.2) and `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
With[{m = Last @ ArrayReduce[Min, data, 1]},
 ReplaceAt[x_ :> x - m, {All, 2}] @ data]
```

{{0.0016, 25.9}, {0.0032, 27.2}, {0.0049, 19.5}, {0.0065,
8.1}, {0.0082, 4.3}, {0.0098, 0.}}

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{0.0016, 60.3}, {0.0032, 61.6}, {0.0049, 53.9},
       {0.0065, 42.5}, {0.0082, 38.7}, {0.0098, 34.4}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's data and using `ReplacePart`:

```
With[{m = Last@First@SortBy[Last]@data}, 
ReplacePart[data, i_ :> data[[i]] - Threaded[{0, m}]]]
```

*Result*:

> {{0.0016, 25.9}, {0.0032, 27.2}, {0.0049, 19.5}, {0.0065,
> 8.1}, {0.0082, 4.3}, {0.0098, 0.}}